# Best way to create an application that allows people to 'register' to a website

Tags: database, registration, facebook-graph-api

I have a music promotion website, I require people to sign a 'copyright' permission form in order for me to display them on my homepage. I know it would be a load quicker if I integrated a Facebook signup with that.

What is the best way to do this?

What will i need to know?

The likely data I would need is the names, general contact information, bio, music likes and some other general information. I would need this data to be stored somewhere secure and somewhere were I could access it as 'evidence' they have confirmed permission to my website.

Answer (score 1):

use the registration plugin that Facebook provides